# Insert two consecutive elements in array at specific Index in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays like this,

```
var firstArray = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven'];
var secondArray =['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'];
```

I have to insert second array elements into first array like this,

```
var combinedArray =['one','two','three','1','2','four','five','six','3','4','seven','5','6','7','8']
```

I know that I could splice and insert at `specific index` for one element. However I am confused how exactly to achieve this pattern.
Could any one help me out with this?

Comment: how do you decide the index?

Comment: I have to insert after every three elements in first array .I thought may be by looping through I could achieve this .But I was unable to do so

Comment: Same question. After how many elements of first array you are supposed to insert the element of the second array?? and how many elements of the second array to be inserted, Is it always 3 element from first array then 2 element of the second array?

Comment: yes it always after three elements in the first array .But if the length of the first array is less than three i need to append the remaining elements in the second array with the first array

Comment: You have `six` twice in your example output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a pattern for the chunks and slice the wanted length for a new array.

```js
var firstArray = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven'],
    secondArray = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'],
    data = [firstArray, secondArray],
    pattern = [3, 2],
    result = [],
    i = 0,
    l = data.reduce(function (r, a) { return Math.max(r, a.length); }, 0);

while (i < l) {
    pattern.forEach(function (a, j) {
        result = result.concat(data[j].slice(i * a, (i + 1) * a));
    });
    i++;
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually splice more than one item:

```
firstArray.splice(3, 0, "1", "2");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create two variables `i` and `j` and increment first one by 3 that you will use to slice first array and increment the second one by 2 and you will use that one to slice second array. If the `i + 3 > a.length` you will concat rest of elements in `b` array to result.

```js
var a = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven'];
var b = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'];
var r = [], i = 0, j = 0

while(i < a.length) {
  r.push(...a.slice(i, i + 3), ...b.slice(j, i + 3 < a.length ? j + 2 : b.length))
  i += 3, j += 2
}

console.log(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

a more granular approach:

```js
var firstArray = ['one','two','three','four','five','six','seven'];
var secondArray =['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'];

var combinedArray = flatten(zip(
  toGroupsOf(3, firstArray), 
  toGroupsOf(2, secondArray)
));

console.log(combinedArray);


//a the utilities for that

function isUint(value){
  return value === (value >>> 0)
}

function toGroupsOf(length, arrayOrString){
  if( !isUint(length) || !length  ) 
    throw new Error("invalid length " + JSON.stringify(length));
  
  return Array.from(
    { length: Math.ceil(arrayOrString.length / length) }, 
    (v,i) => arrayOrString.slice(i*length, (i+1)*length)
  );
}

function zip(...arraysOrStrings){
  var numColumns = arraysOrStrings.length,
      lengths = arraysOrStrings.map(item => (item && +item.length) || 0),
      x=0, y=0;
  return Array.from(
    { length: lengths.reduce((a,b)=>a+b, 0) },
    function(v,i){
      for(var safety = numColumns+1; safety--;){
        if(y < lengths[x])
          return arrays[x++][y];
        else if(++x >= numColumns)
          x=0, ++y;
      }
      throw new Error("something went wrong, this line should have never been reached");
    }
  )
}

function flatten(array){
  return [].concat.apply([], array);
}
```